Blured joints of metal construction rendering
I’m currently working on rendering a stainless steel model and wanted to share an example of my accomplishments. Despite my efforts, I’m not entirely satisfied with the outcomes. Specifically, everything appears blurred at the joint between two components, almost as if it were soldered. I’ve attempted to adjust the lighting to rectify this issue, but unfortunately, these attempts have been unsuccessful.
I would greatly appreciate any advice or tips you might have to offer. Your expertise and suggestions would be invaluable to me as I aim to improve the quality of my rendering.
Thank you in advance for your help and support!

P.S.
I used Cycles rendering with noise threshold 0.01, Denoise enabled, everything else more or less default
P.P.S.


Reflective materials without anything to reflect aren't usually pretty. They need details to reflect, otherwise it's boring. Maybe try using a HDRI for example ?

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Perhaps a silly question, but do you mark as sharp the edges that seem blurred (if I correctly locate where is your issue) ? Could you provide your Blender file using https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Maybe darken the base of the shape so that we see the joint?
